# How to use NSRegularExpression to separate youtube duration like "PT1H50M20S"

Tags: swift

I have a problem with youtube duration.

How to separate this string:

> PT1H50M20S

to `1:50:20` with NSRegularExpression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `NSRegularExpression` here, you can use `NSCharacterSet` instead.

```
let s = "PT1H50M20S"
    s.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet())
.filter { $0 != "" }
.joinWithSeparator(":") // 1:50:20
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Alexander Doloz